# how to use neat's feed forward network by itself?

Tags: python, neural-network, feed-forward

I want to use NEAT's neural network by itself so I can control how the selection of the fittest(training) is done along with other things, but the source code for NEAT's feed forward network can't be used alone(to create one I have to have a config file, and a genome).

Source code for `nn.feed_forward`:

```py
from neat.graphs import feed_forward_layers


class FeedForwardNetwork(object):
    def __init__(self, inputs, outputs, node_evals):
        self.input_nodes = inputs
        self.output_nodes = outputs
        self.node_evals = node_evals
        self.values = dict((key, 0.0) for key in inputs + outputs)

    def activate(self, inputs):
        if len(self.input_nodes) != len(inputs):
            raise RuntimeError("Expected {0:n} inputs, got {1:n}".format(len(self.input_nodes), len(inputs)))

        for k, v in zip(self.input_nodes, inputs):
            self.values[k] = v

        for node, act_func, agg_func, bias, response, links in self.node_evals:
            node_inputs = []
            for i, w in links:
                node_inputs.append(self.values[i] * w)
            s = agg_func(node_inputs)
            self.values[node] = act_func(bias + response * s)

        return [self.values[i] for i in self.output_nodes]


    @staticmethod
    def create(genome, config): # I don't want to have to pass in either arguments to create a network
        """ Receives a genome and returns its phenotype (a FeedForwardNetwork). """

        # Gather expressed connections.
        connections = [cg.key for cg in genome.connections.values() if cg.enabled]

        layers = feed_forward_layers(config.genome_config.input_keys, config.genome_config.output_keys, connections)
        node_evals = []
        for layer in layers:
            for node in layer:
                inputs = []
                for conn_key in connections:
                    inode, onode = conn_key
                    if onode == node:
                        cg = genome.connections[conn_key]
                        inputs.append((inode, cg.weight))

                ng = genome.nodes[node]
                aggregation_function = config.genome_config.aggregation_function_defs.get(ng.aggregation)
                activation_function = config.genome_config.activation_defs.get(ng.activation)
                node_evals.append((node, activation_function, aggregation_function, ng.bias, ng.response, inputs))

        return FeedForwardNetwork(config.genome_config.input_keys, config.genome_config.output_keys, node_evals)
```

Also I want to be able to mutate the neural network(connections, weights, ect).

Comment: Of course you can manually call the `__init__` method, however, it require you to set the `inputs, outputs, node_evals` manually, which is already encapsulated in the `create` method. I think it will be more connveniet to use the `create` method. Why do you want to avoid "have a config file, and a genome"?

Comment: I just want the network by itself.

Comment: I think you should either use the `create` method or set the `inputs, outputs, node_evals` manually. After creation, you can call `activate` without problem. Parameters are needed to create an instance of `FeedForwardNetwork` after all. Perhaps you can write you own class `MyFeedForwardNetwork` by re-implement the `activate` method?

Comment: How do I set the `inputs, outputs, node_evals`, what do they look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a `FeedForwardNetwork`, you need to use the `create` method or set the `inputs, outputs, node_evals` manually.

#### input

The `input` is the list of the "key"(refer to the [doc](https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glossary.html#term-key)) of the *input* nodes. It is a `list` of `int`, like `[-1, -2, ...,-num_inputs]`, where num_inputs is the number of input nodes you set in the [config_file](https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_file.html).

#### output

The `output` is the list of the "key" of the *output* nodes. It is a `list` of `int`, like `[0, 1, 2, ..., (num_outputs-1)]`, where num_outputs is the number of output nodes you set in the config_file.

#### node_evals

The `node_evals` is a list of tuple.

The size of the tuple:

Each element in the tuple correpsonds to one node that have "in" connections, so the tuple size is num_of_hiddens+num_of_outputs in the network. (Note, this is decided by the genome instead of the config, so the "num_of_outputs" and "num_of_hiddens" can be different from the "num_outputs" and "num_hidden" in the config_file).

The elements in the tuple:

As you can see in the `create` method and the `activate` method, an element in the tuple includes:

1. `tuple[0]`: The key of corresponding node.
2. `tuple[1]`: The activation_function of the node. I think it is a function that input a float and output a float.
3. `tuple[2]`: The aggregation_function of the node. I think it can be any function that input a list of float, and output another float. For example, compute the sum of the elements in the list.
4. `tuple[3]`: Bias of the node, float.
5. `tuple[4]`: Response of the node, float.
6. `tuple[5]`: Links that provide inputs for this neuron(node), denoted as node `i`. It is a list of tuple. The length of `tuple[5]` is the number of input neuron of *current* neuron `i`. As for the sub-tuple inside `tuple[5]`, `sub_tuple[0]` is the key of a input neuron (here "input" means a node that input to node `i`, instead of the "input" of the whole network), and the `sub_tuple[1]` (it's of `float` type) is the connection weight between the certain input neuron and node `i`.

If you take a look at the implementation of `activate`, you may have a better understanding of the physical meaning of "activation_function", "aggregation_function", "bias", "response" and "links".

---

I would also suggest you to run an example over [here](https://github.com/CodeReclaimers/neat-python/tree/master/examples/xor), add a breakpoint at the creatation of the `FeedForwardNetwork` and inspect the data type.

Comment: WOW, so its possible... good answer... two questions... 1: What is the 'Response of the node'?, is this to do with the output of the node?? 2: Is the '"key"' in the inputs and the outputs just an identifier(like a tag) and can it be the same as another key?

Comment: @coder 1. You can refer to the `activate` code. First use `agg_func` to aggregate the weighted input. (Standard neuronal network today use sum to aggregate the weighted sum, i.e., compute a weighted sum of input) , then multiply this outcome with the factor `response`,  add with `bias` (Standard neuronal network always set `response=1`) and pass to activation function.  you may also refer to [this link](https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glossary.html?highlight=response#term-response)  2. I think the `key` should be unique. It aslo serve as a key in the dictionary `self.values`.

Comment: Thank you, I won't accept or give bounty yet, I will try this out, if it works(it should), I will accept and give bounty.

Comment: so this: `inputs = [-1, -2, -3, -4]`, `outputs = [0, 1]`, `node_evals = [(2, sigmoid, aggregation, 0.0, 1.0, [(-2, 1), (-1, 1), (-3, 1), (-4, 1)]), (0, sigmoid, aggregation, 0.0, 1.0, [(2 ,1)]), (1, sigmoid, aggregation, 0.0, 1.0, [(2 ,1)])]`
should look like [this](https://pasteboard.co/yfVvenwwm6Q8.png)?

Comment: It looks like it works!!!! Just reply to my previous comment then I will accept and give bounty, you deserve it.

Comment: @coder I think your code will work. Thanks for your generosity.

Comment: [code for future visitors](https://pastebin.com/DT9MpmfV)